# How to select rows from a table only if there's a linked row in a join table?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, join

sorry for the complex title.

I have this schema:

```
Categories  Albums          Photos 
----------  -------         --------
id          id              id
name        category_id     album_id
```

From these tables  I need to build a navigation menu like this:

```
Category1
   album1
   album2
Category2
   album3
Category3
   album4
```

I can easily build this, but now I'd like to show only albums that contain at least one photo and only categories that contain at least one album.
How can I do it?

Edit: 
I'm using Codeigniter and right now I'm doing it this way:

in a controller I build an array using two simple queries

```
 $categories = $this->category->get_categories();

    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        $data['categories'][$category->name] = $this->album->get_albums_by_category($category->id);
    }
```

The get_categories() query:

```
    function get_categories()
{
    $this->db->select('*')->
        from('categories');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

and the get_albums one:

```
    function get_albums_by_category($category_id)
{
    // per stampare il nome dell'album nella lingua giusta
    $lang = $this->lang->lang();
    $name = $lang . '_name';
    $this->db->select('id, ' . $name . ' AS name')
        ->from('albums')
        ->group_by('id')
        ->where('category_id', $category_id);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

I used two queries so that I could be the array as I needed it.

Comment: that should be a regular join . no left or right.

Comment: Please post the query you are currently using. Thanks.

Comment: ok, I edited the question with the queries and more info

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your base query:

```
select (case when thetype = 'Category' then category else album end) as what
from ((select 'category' as thetype, category, NULL as album
       from category
      ) union all
      (select 'album', category, album
       from album a join
            category c
            on a.category_id = c.id
      )
     ) t
order by category, album
```

Now, we can modify this for your question:

```
select (case when thetype = 'Category' then category else album end) as what
from ((select 'category' as thetype, category, NULL as album
       from categories c
       where c.id in (select category_id from albums)
      ) union all
      (select 'album', category, album
       from albums a join
            categories c
            on a.category_id = c.id
       where a.id in (select album_id from photos)
      )
     ) t
order by category, album
```

Comment: In your second query the left part of `UNION ALL` should probably have its condition extended like this: `where c.id in (select category_id from albums where id in (select album_id from photos))`, or you may end up with an album-less category whose albums aren't displayed simply because they don't have photos. Other than that, this is pretty much what I had in mind, and so thanks for saving me the trouble of writing my own answer. :)

Comment: @AndriyM . . . I'm not following your logic.  An album-less category wouldn't be displayed, and there necessarily wouldn't be any photos.  My answer does assume that all albums have valid categories.

Comment: You may be hiding an album that has no photos. But if it was the only album in a category then you would still be displaying that category, even though the album would not be displayed (because you are only checking if a category has albums, but not if a category has albums with photos).

Comment: Very good point . . . it would be up to @Carlo to clarify what he means in this case.  He says "only categories that contain at least one album" but I think your interpretation possibly makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use this technique:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Albums
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Photos
    WHERE Photos.album_id = Album.id
)
```

This is called a correlated subquery and can be slow in some cases if you use it for a full join, but here using just an EXISTS clause, it should be fast.